# How can I hide the other elements when one dropdown menu is click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm still new to Vue.js so far I'm liking it. Currently stuck on drop menus.

If one drop down menu is click is there a way to hide the other menus that are open?

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const hideshow1= ref(false);
const hideshow2= ref(false);
const hideshow3= ref(false);
 
 function show1() {

    this.hideshow1= !this.hideshow1;

};

function show2() {

this.hideshow2= !this.hideshow2;

};
function show3() {

this.hideshow3= !this.hideshow3;

};


</script>


<template>
<button @click="show1()" type="button"> show</button>
<button @click="show2()" type="button"> show</button>
<button @click="show3()" type="button"> show</button>

            <div :class="{'block':hideshow1, 'hidden': !  hideshow1}"    class="sm:hidden ">show1</div>
            <div :class="{'block':hideshow2, 'hidden': !  hideshow2}"     class="sm:hidden ">show2</div>
            <div :class="{'block':hideshow3, 'hidden': !  hideshow3}"    class="sm:hidden ">show3</div>

   </template>
```

Comment: Do you want only one to be visible all the time ?

Comment: Yes, only one. Trying to use the script setup method.

Comment: You could use property like `currentOpen` that will be a number from 1 to 3, and for example in show1 func u set that number to 1, in show2 set its value to 2.... and then in your div's just add check for `currentOpen` == 1 in first, then in second `currentOpen` ==3 ... you get the idea

Comment: I'm probably going to use VueUse add-on. It seems to be the best option for the long run. Thank You

Comment: Why not use `v-if` to toggle visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm grossly over-simplifying your problem, but as I mentioned in comment, why not change your apps data state with the buttons, and then use a v-if to check state of your data, toggling visibility. The data probably should be an array of objects, perhaps something like this:

```
<template>
    <h2>Show Hide Menus</h2>
    <button v-for="item in hideShows" :key="item.text" @click="show(item)">
        Button {{ item.text }} 
    </button>

    <div v-for="item in hideShows" :key="item.text">
        <span v-if="item.value">Show {{ item.text }}</span>
    </div>
</template> 
       
       
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const hideShows = ref([
    {
        text: "1",
        value: true
    },
    {
        text: "2",
        value: false
    },
    {
        text: "3",
        value: false
    }
]);

function setAllFalse() {
    hideShows.value.forEach(hideShow => {
        hideShow.value = false;
    })
}

function show(item) {
    setAllFalse();
    item.value = !item.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still new to Vue.js but that script give me an idea on what do. Thank You